# Create single formula in Google Sheets that joins 2+ QUERY/FILTER functions that return data of various dimensions with blank rows between the output

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like so:

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | 41 |
| a | c | 47 |
| a | c | 23 |
| a | d | 9 |
| a | d | 15 |
| a | d | 75 |
| a | e | 56 |
| b | f | 4 |
| b | f | 22 |
| b | f | 76 |
| b | g | 58 |
| b | g | 68 |
| b | g | 54 |
| b | h | 32 |

I have various queries/filters like:

- `=QUERY(A:C, "SELECT A, SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A")`
- `=QUERY(A:C, "SELECT A, B, SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A, B")`
- `={A1:C1; FILTER(A:C, A:A = "a")}`
- `=QUERY(A:C, "SELECT SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL")`

I want to enter ONE formula in ONE cell and have it output all 3 of these formulas below each other, with 2 blank rows in between. The expected output is:

[image]

As you can see, the issue is that each formula returns a 2d array of different dimensions. So I can't just use `;` to group them into one formula.

These are just some example formulas. In my real world use, I have different formulas that return other sizes: 1 column, 2 columns, 6 columns, etc..

Also, I don't want to use Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=ifna(vstack(QUERY(A:C, "SELECT A, SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A"),
        ,, 
        QUERY(A:C, "SELECT A, B, SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A, B"),
        ,,
        {A1:C1; FILTER(A:C, A:A = "a")},
        ,,
        QUERY(A:C, "SELECT SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL")))
```

[image]